# WebStorm make text file instead needed

Tags: webstorm

After making *.jsx file WebStorm thinks that it is a text file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that this file (or a pattern that represents it) is not listed under

Settings → Editor → File Types→ Text files

For OS X

Preferences → Editor → File Types→ Text files

[image]